# How to fix wrapt and meson-python installation error?

Tags: python-3.10, meson-build, wrapt

I work on **Python 3.10** with `pip` and am trying to install a package from GitHub but I get two errors (which do not seem to be related to the package I am trying to install):

1. ERROR: could not register module: No module named `wrapt`, even though I have `wrapt==0.15.0` in my packages list
2. meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found pip_system_certs: ERROR: could not register module: No module named 'wrapt'
   meson-python: error: 1.2.1
   meson-python: error:
   , even though I have `meson-python==0.12.0` and `meson==1.2.1` installed

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you get this working?